# how to load a ViewController from xib: UIView file? swift 3

Tags: swift, xib, viewcontroller

OK, i have 2 problem here:

1
I try to load a ViewController from a button in the xib file.
This is my button from my xib: UIView.

```
@IBAction func fechaSalida(_ sender: Any) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "calendario") as! CalendarioViewController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

The problem here is the `presentViewController` because my xib is a UIView type, his show me this error: "(value type ViewController) has no member of presentViewController".
Why i try to use this code? is because in my CalendarioViewController i have this code when pressed a button: `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` so this is my first problem...

2
The second problem is when i have this code in a button inside of my xib: UIView, the CalendarioViewController is load ok...but the code: `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` is not working anymore. 
Here my code of my button xib:

```
@IBAction func fechaSalida(_ sender: Any) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc:CalendarioViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "calendario") as! CalendarioViewController
    vc.dateDelegate = self
    self.window!.rootViewController = vc

}
```

> So..how can load a ViewController (CalendarioViewController) and the dismiss code Keep running?

Comment: Find the parent VC of the UIView and perform actions on VC

Comment: sorry...i can't follow you...

Comment: View can't present View Control. So you have to find the View Controller which holds the view, and then present another View Controller from that Parent View Controller

Comment: ah...ok now i get than...i will try! thanks!

Comment: I think the trick is how doing a dismiss from a rootViewController... this code not work: self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Your question is a bit difficult to follow

Answer (score 0):

ok... i have what i need.
For this work i use UITapGestureRecognizer in View Controller which holds the view:

In `override func viewDidLoad()` put this code:

```
    let fechaArriboTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(handleArribo))
    let fechaSalidaTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(handleSalida))
    fechaArribo.addGestureRecognizer(fechaArriboTap)
    fechaSalida.addGestureRecognizer(fechaSalidaTap)
```

Then create the methods:

```
func handleArribo() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc:CalendarioViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "calendario") as! CalendarioViewController
    vc.dateDelegate = self
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func handleSalida() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc:CalendarioViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "calendario") as! CalendarioViewController
    vc.dateDelegate = self
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

and thats is! Thanks @sasquatch